# React-Native AsyncStorage: What exactly does 'clear()' function clear?

Tags: react-native, store, asyncstorage

The [official docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage#clear) about `.clear()` are not very clear to me. They say the following:

> Erases all AsyncStorage for all clients, libraries, etc. You probably don't want to call this; use removeItem or multiRemove to clear only your app's keys. Returns a Promise object.

Can anybody explain, what 'all clients' exactly means in this context? For me it sounds like other RN-Apps stores could be affected too, I just can't imagine that this would even be possible.

Answer (score 1):

It means everything that was stored by apps in asyncstorage will be cleared and yes it includes not only yours but other apps too it is clear from the documentation's this line

> Erases all AsyncStorage for all clients, libraries, etc. You probably
>   don't want to call this **use removeItem or multiRemove to clear only
>   your app's key**s.

Comment: Wow this is crazy, so potentially every App can delete my whole async-storage? This seems horrible from a security perspective. Isn't async storage sandboxed for every App by it's app-id?

Answer (score 0):

means that it will clean everything you have added using `setItem`.

`other RN-Apps stores could be affected too?`

**R/** No, `AsyncStorage` concat a `appId` (or something like that) to your `setItem key` to prevent remove info from another app.

Comment: It looks like there are conflicting answers here. Can you link to their code where it is doing that? 

Otherwise I don't trust it enough to use this function and will have to keep a whitelist and use multiRemove.